# Using 32-bit shared libraries on 64-bit system

Tags: c++, g++, shared-libraries, ubuntu-18.04, 32bit-64bit

I have some libraries with 32-bit architecture which I want to use for compiling on my 64-bit architecture system. Despite that I installed the foreign architecture i386 and gcc-multilib, I still get error by compiling:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible ../rep/Fipe/libOTB.so when searching for -lOTB
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lOTB
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglut
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The shared library has the following specifications:

```
ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, with debug info, not striped
```

Comment: 32 ≠ 64.  To do what you want, you'll need to host the 32 bit shared library in a 32 bit program, and then do IPC from your 64 bit program to your 32 bit helper application.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: ***you cannot***.

GCC-multilib is for cross-compiling: compiling a program for use on a different architecture than the one being used to compile.

It does not do anything to allow you to *execute* code for a different architecture than the one you are using.

tl;dr : you cannot mix 32-bit and 64-bit code in the same process.

<sub>Well, you *can*, but it is a nightmare to do so, and it is really fragile. Unless you have well-defined reasons for it, don’t. There should not be any 32-bit libraries that you cannot also get in 64-bit. (Unless you are running really old, obsolete stuff, in which case you should be compiling a 32-bit program.)</sub>

Comment: But principally it should work to use 32-bit shared libraries with help of gcc-multilib, doesn't it?

Comment: @Digger • gcc-multilib is useful for cross-compiling.

Comment: citation from Debian.org: "Multiarch lets you install library packages from multiple architectures on the same machine. This is useful in various ways, but the most common is installing both 64 and 32-bit software on the same machine and having dependencies correctly resolved automatically."